# c++ ShellExecute "open" in already opened window

Tags: c++, shellexecute, hwnd

```
I'm trying to open a new folder in the same window that is already opened. This is the code:

if (DirectoryExists(myfolder)) {
    HWND currenthwnd,hwnd;

    hwnd=NULL;
    currenthwnd=GetForegroundWindow();
        if (currenthwnd!=hwnd)
        {
        hwnd=currenthwnd;
            if (hwnd!=NULL) 
                {
                ShellExecute(hwnd, "open", myfolder, NULL, NULL, SW_SHOW);
                }
        }
}
```

But it opens a new window everytime. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The `hwnd` which you pass is the *parent* window. In general you can't get random windows to do anything you want them too. You send them a message, and if they understand the message they'll react to it. E.g. `WM_CLOSE` is almost always understood, `WM_COPYDATA` less often.

In this case, it's a bit more complex. You need to find the shell window via `IShellWindows`. and then manage to call its `IExplorerBrowser::BrowseToObject` method. But that's a bit too complex to explain here.